# When resetting password, update function stops working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, reset-password

[image: timeout when uodating]

Here is my code:
password_resets_controller.rb

```
        class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :get_user,         only: [:edit, :update]
      before_action :valid_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
      before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]

      def new
      end

      def create
        # @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_resets]        [:email].downcase)
        @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
        if @user
          @user.create_reset_digest
          @user.send_password_reset_email
          flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def edit
      end

      def update
        if params[:member][:password].empty?
          @user.errors.add(:password, "Can't be empty")
          render 'edit'
        elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          # log_in @user
          flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
          redirect_to @user
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

      private
        def user_params
          params.require(:member).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
        end

        def get_user
          @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
        end

        # Confirms a valid user.
        def valid_user
          unless @user
            redirect_to root_url
          end
        end

        # Check expiration of reset token.
        def check_expiration
          if @user.password_reset_expired?
            flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
            redirect_to new_password_reset_url
          end
        end

    end
```

Thr situation is after I enter the path of password reset token, I put the new password and password_confirmation. Then I click update. However, this error page shows. I really don't know how to figure this out.

Here is my edit file:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
          <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

          <%= hidden_field_tag :email, @user.email %>

          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.submit "Update password", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

Here is the log:[image]

Here is my User table:
[image]

Here is the log after change password_reset_path(params[:id]) to password_reset_path(@user)
[image]

Comment: your params seems to be empty. The problem is in your form. Can you post your params  from your logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your `form` sends `member` key instead of `user`, as your logs show:

```
Parameters: { 
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"...",
  "email"=>"naomi.wuuu@gamil.com",
  "member"=>{
    "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
    "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"
  },
  ...
}
```

So, since there is no `user` key, `params[:user]` returns `nil` and, since it can't respond to `[]`, results in the error:

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Looking at your controller and view I can't see why `member` is being used instead of `user`, but you can force your `form` to send `user` key using `as: "user"`, like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id]), as: "user") do |f| %>
```

With this in place, your parameters will be now:

```
Parameters: { 
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"...",
  "email"=>"naomi.wuuu@gamil.com",
  "user"=>{
    "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
    "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: What if i want to keep params[:user][:password].empty? What should i do?  By the way, how can you tell that the form send member key instead of user?

Comment: How can I make the form key to the user not member?

Comment: I can tell where is the problem right now. Thanks. But after I change to member. There is one more problem. NoMethodError (undefined method `member_url' for #<PasswordResetsController:0x007f9642b8d140>):

Comment: @NaomiWu could you please edit your question and include the `edit` action of the controller?

Comment: @NaomiWu I can't figure out what is causing your form to use `member`, but i updated the question with an alternate solution that could help you. Check it out.